# Array of size 2GB throws memory error at subtraction and division operations

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I have loaded a numpy array of roughly 2gb and I got memory error when I try to normalize its entries:

```
 import numpy as np
 fX = 'train_X.npy'
 imgs = np.load(fX)
 #normalize
 X = (imgs - 128.)
 X = X / 255.
```

X contains 10000 rgb images so it is of shape (10012, 210, 320, 3) and X.bytes returns 2018419200. I'm using a Ubuntu server distro (google cloud) with available 14gb of ram, python and numpy are in 64bits so I don't really see the issue... Any idea?

Comment: Try using `np.subtract` and `np.divide` with their argument `out = ` to write back the results into input and hence save memory.

Comment: @Divakar same problem...

Comment: Where exactly is the mem error happening? Which step?

Comment: X = (imgs - 128.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array imgs is of type `uint8`, each entry takes one byte of memory. So the array takes 2018419200 bytes, about 1.88 GB.

Subtracting 128. (a floating-point number) casts the array to `float64` (double precision floats), which takes 8 bytes per number. That makes the size 15 GB, hence the memory error.

You can save the situation by casting the array to single precision, `float32` will take half as much space (7.5 GB).

```
X = np.load(fX).astype(np.float32)
X -= 128.
X /= 255.
```

The augmented assignment operations are done in-place, so there will not be an intermediate copy created.

You could also try `float16` type (see all [data types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types)) but many NumPy/SciPy methods expect either float64 or float32 so you may end up with larger array anyway.

(Another option is to keep the array as `uint8` and figure out how to do what you wanted to do with it without normalization and associated conversion to floats.)